# Are certificates required for client-only SSL/TLS apps?

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate

I am trying to develop a minimal *client-only* SSL/TLS app to connect to an https server. It always fails on on 'SSL_connect().  I haven't installed any certificates.
**Are certicates required in such a case?**
I've found many answers on SO and elsewhere that say NO with the caveat *"unless required by the server"*.

**Details:**

- I'm using the GitHub: OpenSSL package which I built from source.
- All SSL calls prior to SSL_connect succeed,
- On debugging, I see the error happening in function 'SSL_do_handshake' [returns -1].
- I'e tried several different https servers with the same result.
- I'm using MSVC 2019 on a Dell Optiplex Win10/64 machine
- Ideally, I'd like to avoid certificates to avoid having (non-tech-savvy) end-users having to muck with certificates.

**Code Synopsis:**

- Get method: TLS_client_method()
- Get CTX: SSL_CTX_new(method)
- Create socket 'sock'
- Connect sock to host on port 443
- Create SSL*: ssl=SSL_new(ctx)
- SSL_set_fd(ssl, sock)
- SSL_connect(ssl) [always fails]

Comment: When a libssl routine returns 'failure' you should check `SSL_get_error()` and if it is `SSL_ERROR_SSL` as it will be here look at the error stack e.g. with `ERR_print_errors[+_fp`; see the man pages. Though here it _probably_ will just tell you `alert handshake_failure`. In addition to some servers that require client authentication by certificate, many servers today require SNI (aka host name) which your code doesn't provide. Try running `openssl s_client -connect host:443 [if1.1.1: -noservername] -debug` to find out what _and when_ the error is, and if client cert is requested.

Comment: Also if you don't realize, by default OpenSSL doesn't not verify the server cert or identity, so your connections can easily be intercepted, exposed, and altered. If you or your users are using HTTPS because you or they want security, they won't get it, and if for example they go out of business because of your design they may be displeased with you. OTOH if your app's data is always worthless and ignored, and you're only doing HTTPS because many servers, networks, or admins now require it, that's fine.

Comment: @Dave, yes, the error was SSL_ERROR_SSL. I didn't understand "ERR_print_errors[+_fp" notation.  I also tried to connect as suggested with "openssl s_client -connect fax.plus:443" but didn't know how to interpret the response. I posted it on my web site at www.ramrodtechnology.com/badconnect.html. I also tried creating/installing a self-signed certificate but not sure I did that right. No difference. Still confused.

Comment: @Dave, ref security: not a concern, my data is "worthless".

Comment: (1) I mistyped without noticing; I intended `ERR_print_errors[_fp]` which means "either `ERR_print_errors` or `ERR_print_errors_fp`" (the `_fp` part can be added or not) which are similar though distinct and both are described on the same man page, along with a third adding `_cb`. In most programs the `_fp` version using a C-library `FILE*` is easiest, especially with `stdout` or `stderr`. (2) your commandline was _successful_; was that `openssl` the same build as your application is using? If so it really shouldn't have differed.

Comment: (3) Did you use a tag or branch or 'head' from github? 'head' is currently for alpha-testing the upcoming (we hope) 3.0.0 release, which I am not set up to debug, although to my understanding the libssl part (i.e. the ssl/ subdirectory) doesn't change much.

Comment: Dave, I tried "ERR_print_errors_fp(stdout)" but it jusr printed "OPENSSL_Uplink(&A&F308,08): no OPENSSL_Applink" (???).

Comment: Dave: Ref: lib version: I always used the same library (the only one I built). Ref: GitHub: I don't know about "branch", I simply used "git clone git://git.openssl.org/openssl.git"

Comment: Okay, fortunately that problem is not related to unreleased 3.0.0 stuff that would have been difficult for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"no Applink" explains the failure -- even though it caused ERR_print_errors_fp to also fail.

On Windows to pass opened files or sockets from your exe to the OpenSSL library *if* linked as DLL (which is the default, but overridable) you must **compile and link into your application exe the supplied file include/openssl/applink.c** (note .c not .h -- it's an *include* file but not a *header* file). See https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/OPENSSL_Applink.html (though it's brief; I'm sure I've seen a better explanation somewhere, decades ago, but I can't find it now).

On MSVC I *think* you can just 'add' this file, or a copy, to your project and it will get compiled and linked automatically, but I no longer use it myself and can't verify. You *may* need to #include the file somewhere appropriate, like your main.c .

Comment: Including applink.c fixed "ERR_print_errors_fp()". Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, simple answer to my problem. Turns out there was a problem with the server I was testing against. When I tried to connect to another, e.g., "feistyduck.com" or "google.com" on port 443, all was good.